# Data Consumed/Downloaded by Networked Devices

Tags: wireless-networking, download

Is it possible to determine how much data a certain device on a network has consumed/downloaded?

For example, I have two laptops, a Kindle Fire HD, two mobile phones plus a couple of games consoles and a TiVo box all linked up to my broadband and I would like to know if it is possible to see how much one of my laptops is consuming / has consumed/downloaded.

I have a Virgin Media Super Hub and have taken a thorough look through all of the advanced settings and although I can find out how much data has been downloaded per session (the length of a session is measured against how long the Super Hub is continuously switched on for), but I cannot break this info down further to find out how much of the data each device is responsible for.

Furthermore, I have also identified each device by both the device name and also the unique MAC address (as opposed to the IP address as a dynamic IP address is allocated to each device each time it connects to the router, which is not consistent).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Many thanks.